# How to prevent batching with React-Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, batching, react-thunk

I am trying to explain the React-Redux [batch() function](https://react-redux.js.org/api/batch) on my [website](https://webcodingcenter.com/redux/connect()). In order to do so, I need a counterexample without using batch() so that the reader can see the difference. However, [as you can see here on CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-redux-batching-njs034), I couldn't get the counterexample to work, as batching occurred even with multiple asynchronous operations, ie. the number is incremented by two instead of one.

Could someone provide a working counterexample?

```
// index.js
import React from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import reducer from "./reducer";
import App from "./App";

const store = createStore(reducer, 0, applyMiddleware(thunk));

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));

root.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
);
```

...

```
// reducer.js
export default function (state, action) {
  // a reducer
  if (typeof state === "undefined") return 0;
  switch (action.type) {
    case "INCREMENT":
      return state + 1;
    case "DECREMENT":
      return state - 1;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

...

```
// App.js
import { batch, connect } from "react-redux";

function delay(sec) {
  // an asynchronous operation
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, sec * 1000);
  });
}
function delayed_increment(sec) {
  // a thunk
  return function (dispatch, getState) {
    delay(sec)
      .then(() => dispatch({ type: "INCREMENT" }))
      .then(delay(sec))
      .then(() => dispatch({ type: "INCREMENT" }));
  };
}
const App = ({ v, dispatch }) => {
  console.log("rendering...", v);
  return (
    <div>
      <span>{v}</span>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          dispatch(delayed_increment(3));
        }}
      >
        +
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  console.log("mapStateToProps() invoked");
  return { v: state };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

Comment: Interesting behavior in your codesandbox that I would not have expected. However the docs say about `batch`: `You can use it to ensure that multiple actions dispatched outside of React only result in a single render update`. You are clearly dispatching *inside* React. I've tried to adjust your codesandbox so that it dispatches *outside* react, but the behavior is the same. The only thing that successfully triggered multiple renders is using a `setTimeout` with slightly increased delays. My guess is that something internally has changed and the documentation doesn't reflect that yet.

Comment: I dug up a statement from gaearon during the discussion of https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11171 that might contribute to solving this: `we use a polyfill that's internally implemented on top of requestAnimationFrame`. It could be that when the re-renders would fall into the same animation frame, they are simply skipped. It is noticable in your codesandbox that `mapStateToProps` gets called correctly with every incremented value, but not the body of the function component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'React 18 adds out-of-the-box performance improvements by doing more batching by default, removing the need to manually batch updates in application or library code. '

I was using React 18 on CodeSandbox. Earlier versions do not do automatic batching like React 18.

(see [reference here](https://github.com/reactwg/react-18/discussions/21) and [here](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/discussions/1899))